# Docker Composer: unable to connect to a MySQL container from a Net Core Web API container

Tags: mysql, docker, .net-core, docker-compose

this is my first question on Stackoverflow, I was forced because despite finding different solutions to my problem none of them worked for me.

I am trying to study the docker composting system and have created a configuration file that includes four elements: web, API, DB, and phpMyAdmin.

Initially, it was composed of only three elements web, DB, and phpMyAdmin, once I was sure that everything worked properly I moved on to the next step, that of adding the API.

Unfortunately, there was no way to connect the API to the DB, although phpMyAdmin is able to connect to the DB without any problem.
Obviously, the same API launched in debug and configured to connect to the local MySQL server works without any problem.

This is the yml file that I'm trying to get to work:

```
version: '3.3'

services:
    web:
        env_file:
            - DockerImg/email.env
        build:
            context: .
            dockerfile: DockerImg/web.Dockerfile
        container_name: armedia-web
        ports:
            - 8080:80
        volumes:
            - "./DockerImg/web:/var/www/html"
            - "./DockerImg/php/php.ini:/usr/local/etc/php/php.ini"
        links:
            - db
        depends_on:
            - db

    api:
        build:
            context: .
            dockerfile: Dockerfile
        container_name: armedia-api
        ports:
            - 8082:80
        links:
            - db
        depends_on:
            - db
        env_file:
            - DockerImg/dbarmedia.env
        environment:
            - DBHOST=db

    db:
        build:
            context: .
            dockerfile: DockerImg/db.Dockerfile
        container_name: armedia-db
        volumes:
            - "./DockerImg/db:/var/lib/mysql"
        environment:
            - MYSQL_USER=root
            - MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=******
            - MYSQL_DATABASE=armedia

    phpmyadmin:
        image: phpmyadmin/phpmyadmin:4.8.3
        container_name: armedia-phpmyadmin
        ports:
            - 8081:80
        links:
            - db
        depends_on:
            - db
        environment:
            - PMA_HOST=db
            - PMA_USER=root
            - PMA_PASSWORD=******
```

dbarmedia.env contains:

```
DBUSER=root
DBPASS=******
DBNAME=armedia
```

First of all, whatever I write on env_file or environment of the API section does not affect the connectionstring that is actually used by the API.
In fact, when it goes in error, it writes the connectionstring and this is exactly what I put in the appsettings.json of the API project:

```
{
  "Logging": {
    "LogLevel": {
      "Default": "Information",
      "Microsoft.AspNetCore": "Warning"
    }
  },
  "AllowedHosts": "*",
  "ConnectionStrings": {
      "Default": "Server=db;Port=3306;Uid=root;Pwd=******;Database=armedia;"
  }
}
```

The error it returns to me is "Error: Couldn't connect to server"

I tried to replace DB with 127.0.0.1 or localhost, also put db:3306 and 127.0.0.1:3306 as found on some suggestions but it doesn't work, at most the error varies from "Error: Couldn't connect to server" to "Error: Unable to connect to any of the specified MySQL hosts."

I would be very happy if someone could give me some suggestions on how to solve it because I have been looking for a solution without success for days and I think this configuration I am trying is quite "particular"

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: I would start by looking if teh deocker container armedia-db is running with `docker ps` , if not you can see with `docker logs armedia-db` what is happening. From how it looks it should be ok to connect from your app to the db container so I suspect the container is not running.

Comment: Thanks Claudiu, I should see how to check these logs, however I believe that armedia-db works well as if I access localhost:8081, on phpMyAdmin, from there I see the db without problems, while from localhost:8082 the API works but fails to connect to the DB, there must be something that prevents API from connecting to the DB

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to solve the problem and I am exposing the solution because it might be useful to someone.
Actually the problem was related to the MySQL version.
Apparently Net 6 must have some incompatibility problems with the version I was using on the Docker Container:

```
FROM mysql: 5.7.21
```

Only time later did I ask myself the question, which version am I using on the PC where the connection works?

```
mysql Ver 8.0.31-0ubuntu0.20.04.1 for Linux on x86_64 ((Ubuntu))
```

I then changed the Dockefile of the db to:

```
FROM mysql:8.0.31
```

And as if by magic it started working properly.

I hope you find it useful, good evening.