# Failed connection to Mysql DB on Docker from WEBAPI Net 6

Tags: mysql, docker, .net-6.0

Good evening, I'm having a strange problem that I don't know if it is due to a limitation of MySQL or a configuration.
I also believe that the problem is closely related to another problem on which I have requested assistance but which is still not solved, at this link: [Docker Composer: unable to connect to a MySQL container from a Net Core Web API container](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73927708/docker-composer-unable-to-connect-to-a-mysql-container-from-a-net-core-web-api)

Basically I have two MySQL databases on the same PC with Linux Mint OS, the first is present directly on the PC, the second is instead present on a Docker Container which is part of a Docker-Compose.

The first is accessible from localhost at the standard port 3306 while the second is visible from the outside from port 3307 while inside the Docker Compose with the classic port 3306.

I have a WEBAPI that seamlessly connects to the first db with this connection string:
server=localhost;port=3306;user=root;password=******;database=armedia;

If I try to connect instead to the db present on Docker Container with this connection string:
server=localhost;port=3307;user=root;password=******;database=armedia;

It gives me the error: couldn't connect to server

Thinking there was some kind of problem with the visibility of the PC towards the db on Docker Container I tried to test the connection to the db from a local PHP page using the connection first:
$ dbh = new PDO ("mysql:host=localhost; dbname=armedia", "root", "******");

And then the connection:
$ dbh = new PDO ("mysql:host=localhost:3307;dbname=armedia", "root", "******");

The connection works well in both cases and obviously it is clear from the result of a select that in the first case I am connecting to the db locally while in the second case I am connecting to the db on Docker Container.

At this point, I really don't know what it could depend on, I tried to do some research and "play" with the connection string but nothing, the WEBAPI can't connect to the db on Docker Container.

Could you tell me if it depends on the db on Docker Container that to accept connections from Net 6 must be configured in a certain way?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

I managed to solve the problem and I present the solution, which obviously also solves the original problem on the post I linked before, because it might be useful to someone.
Actually the problem was related to the MySQL version.

At a certain point I doubted that the MySQL version could be the problem, even if regardless of the MySQL version, PHP worked correctly, I then checked the version on the Docker Image:
FROM mysql: 5.7.21

And the version on the PC:

```
mysql Ver 8.0.31-0ubuntu0.20.04.1 for Linux on x86_64 ((Ubuntu))
```

I then changed the Dockerfile of the db to:

```
FROM mysql: 8.0.31
```

And as if by magic it started working properly.

Apparently Net 6 must have some incompatibility issues with the version I was using on the Docker Container, which PHP apparently doesn't have.

I hope you find it useful, good evening.